# Python Pandas loc keyerror

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eurusd = pd.read_csv("G:\Kuliah python\EURUSD_M15.csv",sep="\t")

print(eurusd.loc['2020-04-03 21:15'])
```

it shows an error :

```
KeyError: '2020-04-03 21:15'
```

### Here is my data

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th><th>Time</th><th>Open</th><th>High</th><th>Low</th><th>Close</th><th>Volume</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>2020-04-03 21:00:00</td><td>1.07893</td><td>1.07936</td><td>1.07839</td><td>1.07868</td><td>4380</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2020-04-03 21:15:00</td><td>1.07867</td><td>1.07943</td><td>1.07831</td><td>1.07889</td><td>4860</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>2020-04-03 21:30:00</td><td>1.07888</td><td>1.07908</td><td>1.07762</td><td>1.07783</td><td>4022</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>2020-04-03 21:45:00</td><td>1.07782</td><td>1.08059</td><td>1.07727</td><td>1.07975</td><td>6816</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>2020-04-03 22:00:00</td><td>1.07975</td><td>1.08093</td><td>1.07920</td><td>1.08059</td><td>582</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Show textual information properly formatted (and maybe shortened to the relevant part) in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Tell us how you create the dataframe! The dtypes are important. And if date and time are not in the index, it's no surprise that your .loc indexing fails.

Comment: When you pass a single key into [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), it uses that to look up a row based on the DataFrame's index.  But in your example you are using the default index.  Presumably you want to use `eurusd = eurusd.set_index('Time')` first, or `eurusd.loc[eurusd['Time'] == '2020-04-03 21:15']`

Comment: Thank you so much, eurusd = eurusd.set_index('Time') worked perfectly, so the problem was that the index is not set to time, and that makes loc key error. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give it a try: Set the first column as index and your .loc[] indexing works properly.

```
eurusd = pd.DataFrame(
    [['2020-04-03 21:00:00', 1.07893, 1.07936, 1.07839, 1.07868, 4380],
    ['2020-04-03 21:15:00', 1.07867, 1.07943, 1.07831, 1.07889, 4860],
    ['2020-04-03 21:30:00', 1.07888, 1.07908, 1.07762, 1.07783, 4022],
    ['2020-04-03 21:45:00', 1.07782, 1.08059, 1.07727, 1.07975, 6816],
    ['2020-04-03 22:00:00', 1.07975, 1.08093, 1.07920, 1.08059, 582]]
).set_index(0)

eurusd.loc['2020-04-03 21:15:00']

1       1.07867
2       1.07943
3       1.07831
4       1.07889
5    4860.00000
Name: 2020-04-03 21:15:00, dtype: float64
```

You can improve this even further by making the index a DateTimeIndex:

```
eurusd.index = pd.to_datetime(eurusd.index)
```

This allows for "partial string indexing" like

```
eurusd.loc['2020-04-03 21']

2020-04-03 21:00:00 1.07893 1.07936 1.07839 1.07868 4380
2020-04-03 21:15:00 1.07867 1.07943 1.07831 1.07889 4860
2020-04-03 21:30:00 1.07888 1.07908 1.07762 1.07783 4022
2020-04-03 21:45:00 1.07782 1.08059 1.07727 1.07975 6816
```

which gives you all rows between 21:00 and 22:00 exclusive.